# c++ templates dependent on input from file

Tags: c++, templates, io

I have a complicated c++ scientific code, that uses multiple libraries.
Imagine that there are 5 different types of libraries, like linear solver, integration tool, etc. For each library type there are several different libraries that do exactly the same thing, but have different internal implementation. In fact, for every library a wrapper class is implemented, such that all libraries of the same type have exactly the same interface.

Now, I want to give this software to a user. I want user to be able to select the libraries they want to use after the code is already compiled. Currently it is done by means of an input file.

The only problem is coding this in the main program. When coding library selection, I end up using nested ifs, thus explicitly coding every possible combination of the libraries, conditioned on the parameters read from the file. I was wondering if there was a tidy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement templates dependent in input from files, since template types are resolved in compilation, not runtime.

The tidy way to do this is by polymorphism (also, the elegant way ;D).

Define a Base class that defines the interface for each implementation, create the Children classes each one with it's own implementation, and then, (using input from file...or not... your call) resolve which algorithm to use by polymorphism.

:) Good luck.

Comment: Using templates with input from file is done this way
    a = read_file_a();
    if (a == 1)   {  do_sth<1>(); }
    if (a == 2)   {  do_sth<2>(); }

This code works perfectly well with exception that it gets ugly with multiple template parameters.

I can not immediately see how to implement your advice, could you write a short snippet with 2 template parameters?

Comment: Yes, that should work! 
Although by doing that, you are not actually resolving the templates using input from files, you are just selecting which compiled (already resolved) version of the template you'll use depending on the input... And considering this, there is a more elegant way of doing this, which is using design patterns and polymorphism, for instance, by using a Factory to produce the desired object depending on the input you get from the file, or maybe Decorator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)
I assume that the above patterns use dynamic polymorphism, right? Generally, I was told to fear it as fire since it has a little bit of performance overhead. Do you know how significant this overhead would be in this case, and if it would only happen during the initialization of the class, or during every call?

Comment: I worked 4 years developing softwares to simulate flow of oil, gas and water through 3d porous media (petroleum reservoirs) with gas being able to dissolve in water and oil...in other words, a pretty complicated and hard to solve problem that requires performance... so I have a little experience in this, and my opinion on this matter is:
Code it clean, elegant, reusable, easy to understand and modify, don't worry about performance early on, and when working on performance, focus on changing algorithms (which actually have a BIG impact on performance) and do not worry with petty stuff

Comment: Like variable initializations, inline, reusing bizarrely named variables (because they represent more than one thing). And use polymorphism, it helps you a lot in this case.
Though, it is important to know what you're doing, and to avoid unnecessary copies, use lots of references and pointers (preferably smart pointers) and use smart algorithms and data storage structures.

Comment: There are lots of arguments in defense of using clean code, even for performance hungry softwares, but my fav one for your case is that is favors reusability, because you must have spent a lot of time writing a good scientific code, carefully choosing the appropriate algorithm, carefully implementing this algorithm so it actually represents the theory, so it is actually very rewarding when you finish the software and then you see people actually putting your library/software to use.

Comment: Just to finish, it doesn't make sense to worry too much with little things these days, the compiler will simply ignore the "improvements" you do (regarding inline, variable initializations, variable saving, etc) and do whatever it "feels" like doing, and it'll probably be better than anything you do. So you can relax and write an elegant code, it is a fallacy to say that an elegant code lacks performance.